# look for a value in an array with map and find

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object and I want to write a function to look for the chat_userID and return the corresponding nome.

I came up with:

```js
utenti_chat = [{
    "nome": "John Doe",
    "id": 5,
    "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "chat_userID": "c1f2580cad95fa0f"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Jane Doe",
    "id": 6,
    "email": "jane.doe@google.com",
    "chat_userID": "ed86742608dde1fe"
  }
]


userConnected = utenti_chat.filter(a => a.chat_userID.find(w => w == user.userID)).map(a => a.nome);
```

but it returns that

```
a.chat_userID.find is not a function
```

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you use the `filter` method which won't be that helpful here. Then, you call `find` on a variable which its type is an `string`, which has no method called `find` so that is why you get the error.

So given some input, say `userId` the way to get what you want would be,

```js
userId = "c1f2580cad95fa0f";

utenti_chat = [{
    "nome": "John Doe",
    "id": 5,
    "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "chat_userID": "c1f2580cad95fa0f"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Jane Doe",
    "id": 6,
    "email": "jane.doe@google.com",
    "chat_userID": "ed86742608dde1fe"
  }
]


userConnected = utenti_chat.find(a => a.chat_userID === userId)?.nome;

console.log(userConnected);
```

Keep in mind you should handle edge cases, mostly where could not find a matching user with the `userId`. This is why I used the `(...)?.nome` expression. The `?` operator stands for handling that case I described. When a matching user object won't be found, the value of `utenti_chat.find(a => a.chat_userID === userId)` would be `null`. In that case if you won't user the `?` operator you will get run time error for trying to access `nome` key of a `null`.

Comment: the interesting thing in your answer is that it returns directly the string and not an array with just the string inside

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the inner `find`, because `filter` already does the searching for you:

```js
let expectedUserId = "ed86742608dde1fe"

utenti_chat = [{
    "nome": "John Doe",
    "id": 5,
    "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
    "chat_userID": "c1f2580cad95fa0f"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Jane Doe",
    "id": 6,
    "email": "jane.doe@google.com",
    "chat_userID": "ed86742608dde1fe"
  }
]


userConnected = utenti_chat.find(a => a.chat_userID == expectedUserId);
if (userConnected == null) {
    console.log("Not found")
} else {
    console.log(userConnected.nome)
}
```

Comment: I came up also with `utenti_chat.find(a=>a.chat_userID.includes(user.userID));` that does quite the same. Is there an option to return just the value as a string and not as an array in your solution?

Comment: You return an array of 1 size containing the matched name, but he asked to get the matched name, not an array. Should return value of type `string`, not `object` (array)

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes, you can use `find` directly as shown in the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to filter the utenti_chat array based on the condition that the chat_userID matches a specific value (user.userID). However, there's a small mistake in your code. The chat_userID property is a string, so you don't need to use .find() on it. Instead, you can directly compare it.

```
  const utenti_chat = [
{
  "nome": "John Doe",
  "id": 5,
  "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
  "chat_userID": "c1f2580cad95fa0f"
},
{
  "nome": "Jane Doe",
  "id": 6,
  "email": "jane.doe@google.com",
  "chat_userID": "ed86742608dde1fe"
}
  ];
  
  const userConnected = utenti_chat
    .filter(user => user.chat_userID === user.userID)
    .map(user => user.nome);
  
  console.log(userConnected);
```

In this corrected code:

I replaced .find(w => w == user.userID) with === to directly compare chat_userID with user.userID.
The filtered array is then mapped to extract the nome property.
Make sure that user.userID is defined before using this function to avoid any potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
a => a.chat_userID == user.userID
```

in your `filter()`

Comment: This won't help, he'd get return value of type `object` (array) instead of `string` as he asked for

Comment: I'm sorry...I didn't read his question fully...